# how to make many buttons on box with shadow

Tags: html, button, shadow, box

I want to know how to make box with non sharm edges with colorful shodows, in box many colors without borders. please help me. I am new in programing.

I want you to give me some examples to how to do it . In this its your and mine both benifit if you forgot something than it might help you to recap. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

is this what you want to achieve

```css
body{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  height:100vh;
}

.box{
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  background-color:red;
  border-radius:20px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,255,0);
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```